# Phantomjs check if javascript exists and is working

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am quite new to Phantomjs and am starting to getting to know how to use it. However all of the semi advanced tutorials does not cover the thing i want to use Phantomjs for.

Now my question is how would i check if a Javascript is active on the site and if it is working correcly (i.e not throwing erros in the console).

I hope someone is able to point me in the right direction or know how to do this.

Comment: I think you're looking for this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript

Comment: @ep0 doesnt look like it i need to call the phantomjs from php

Comment: what do you mean by "check if a javascript is active" ?

Comment: @fusio checking if it is loaded onLoad() like when the site is loaded is the javascript loaded aswell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if my javascript is loaded on a site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329760/check-if-my-javascript-is-loaded-on-a-site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can interact with the open page using the [webpage.evaluate](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) method:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://m.bing.com', function(status) {
    var title = page.evaluate(function(s) {
        //what you do here is done in the context of the page
        //this console.log will appear in the virtual page console
        console.log("test")
        //here they are just returning the page title (tag passed as argument) 
        return document.querySelector(s).innerText;
        //you are not required to return anything
    }, 'title');
    console.log(title);
    phantom.exit(); //closes phantom, free memory!
});
```

in order to see the virtual page console, you have to add a [onConsoleMessage callback](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html):

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
    console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
};
```

EDIT: by default javascript is executed.

Comment: instead of the title is there a way i can get a list of all javascripts being loaded?

Comment: you mean the `<script>` elements? inside evaluate you can do everything you can in a normal browser. 

how would you get all the scripts in a normal page? I guess something like `document.querySelector('script')` ;)

Comment: if i do this i get: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector(s).innerText')

  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():6
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():8
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():8
null

Comment: the example I provided is working, try it yourself by copying it to a js file and running `phantomjs file.js` in a terminal :) 

that error means that `document.querySelector(s)`returned `null`, i.e. it did not find `s` which in this example is the page `title`

Comment: but there is a script with the name i passed so it should find somethin

Comment: `Array.forEach.apply(document.querySelectorAll('script'), [(function(elem){ console.log(elem.getAttribute('src'));}])` Will list all script sources included in the current page.

Comment: yeah @MarcRasmussen - `querySelectorAll('title')` gets the `title` element, therefore you cannot do `querySelectorAll('scriptName')`: it would look for the non-existing `scriptName` element.. do as @elias-van-ootegem suggests :)