# Check if my javascript is loaded on a site

Tags: php, javascript, testing, web, phantomjs

I have asked this question before but it seems i got misunderstood therefore i decided to ask again but this time with alot of information:

For the lazy reader my goal here is:

> Is there a way to check if a javascript is enabled on an external site either from  PHP or through Ajax

**Detailed description:**

Okay, so my company, has many clients, when these clients sign up on our website, they are handed a `javascript`. They can then use this `script` on their own website to get some extra features.

Now all of the websites, that a client has, is stored within our CMS system (like there is a list of all of the websites they have that are signed with us).

Now my boss gave me the following assignment:

> We need a function so that the user can press the button "Test" and the system will test if the javascript is on their site and working without errors (i.e is there another script blocking ours).

Now the past couple of days, i have been trying to find similar cases on the `web` and the only thing i have been suggested, was Phantomjs however there are NO examples on how to even get close to what i want to achieve.

So my question to you:

1. is it possible to check if a site has a certain javascript.
2. is it possible to check if the javascript is running without errors(if the console throws errors or not)

I hope, that i wont get misunderstood this time :) if you have any questions, please just leave a message, and i will respond as fast as possible!

**The phantomJs Solution (origianlly posted by Elias)**

This is my code:

```
   var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onConsoleMessage = function( message, line, srcId)
{//show console errors for page
    console.log('Page has errors showing in console: ' + msg
        + ' (line: ' + (line || '?') + ', id: ' + srcId + ')');
};
page.open('http://www.marcrasmussen.com',function(status)
{
    if (status != 'success')
    {//can't load page
        console.log('Failed to open page: ' + status);
        phantom.exit();
        return;
    }
    var reslt = page.evaluate(function()
    {
        var usesOurScript = false,
            scripts = document.querySelectorAll('script');//get all script tags
        Array.forEach.apply(scripts, [function(elem)
        {//check all loaded scripts
              if (/jquery\.js/.js.js.test(elem.getAttribute('src')))
            {//this src attribute refers your script
                usesOurScript = true;//set to true
            }
        }]);
        return {page: location.href, found: usesOurScript};//return its href and the use-status
    });
    //script was found? adjust message
    reslt.found = (reslt.found ? ' uses ' : ' does not use ') + 'our script!';
    console.log(reslt.page + reslt.found);//logs url does not use || uses our script
    phantom.exit();
});
```

And there is no output it just keeps running forever when i run it from php:

**Test.php**

```
<?php echo shell_exec('phantomjs hello.js');

?>
```

Comment: This would probably be easier to implement via the code being loaded to the client's site. I.E. Having that code do a POST to your database when an error occurs with one or more of it's functions.

Comment: The only way I can think of is actually going to the site(s) and checking the console. Or have your js (you supplied to clients) send error messages via ajax to a script on your server

Comment: @class how can i check the console of a site without doing it manually?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen I don't think you can as far as I know.

Comment: Or you could host the js on your server and check logs for when the js file was accessed and by whom and implement a error function to post errors to a script on your server

Comment: @Class by hosting the js you mean host it as an external url (like you can do with Jquery) ? ?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen have it on your server and have link like: `myweb.com/somefolder/js/yourscript.js` plus you can make changes whenever you want and it will update all refering to the new js.

Comment: @Class is there a way in the script you "log" which website accesses it and if there is any errors with that specefic website

Comment: @MarcRasmussen the logs usually show what ip/referring url accessed your script. Also in your js file have a send_errors function to send errors to your server w/domain name and what error happened. Some errors you won't be able to catch, but you can have blocks of code that catch missing variable or such. Do a google search for how to implement error detection in js plus how to send data to remote server via post/ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll post it here, too. Since I was the guy that put you on to phantomjs, it's only fair to provide you with, what I think, is the answer to your problems.
The following script opens a page in the headless phantom browser, logs any console messages that page would yield in an actual browser, (using the `onConsoleMessage` event), it also logs the error if the page were to be unable to load, and, if the page was opened without issues, it checks all `<script>` tags on that page, looking for your javascript file.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onConsoleMessage = function( message, line, srcId)
{//show console errors for page
    console.log('Page has errors showing in console: ' + msg
                + ' (line: ' + (line || '?') + ', id: ' + srcId + ')');
};
page.open('http://www.your-url-here.org',function(status)
{
    if (status != 'success')
    {//can't load page
        console.log('Failed to open page: ' + status);
        phantom.exit();
        return;
    }
    var reslt = page.evaluate(function()
    {
        var usesOurScript = false,
        scripts = document.querySelectorAll('script');//get all script tags
        /* Array.forEach is causing errors, as it turns out...
        Array.forEach.apply(scripts, [function(elem)
        {//check all loaded scripts
            if (/yourScriptName\.js/.test(elem.getAttribute('src')))
            {//this src attribute refers your script
                usesOurScript = true;//set to true
            }
        }]);*/
        for (var i=0;i<scripts.length;i++)
        {
            if (/yourScriptName\.js/.test(scripts[i].getAttribute('src')))
            {
                return {page: location.href, found: true};
            }
        }
        return {page: location.href, found: false};
    });
    //script was found? adjust message
    reslt.found = (reslt.found ? ' uses ' : ' does not use ') + 'our script!';
    console.log(reslt.page + reslt.found);//logs url does not use || uses our script
    phantom.exit();
});
```

If that file is does something like jQ (create a global reference to some object) you might even add this to the `page.evaluate` callback:

```
    var reslt = page.evaluate(function()
    {//this code will behave like it's running on the target page
        var libs = {jQuery: ($ || jQuery),
                    myLib: ourLibsGlobalName};
        return libs;
    });
    if (reslt.jQuery instanceof Object)
    {
        console.log('client uses jQ');
    }
    if (reslt.myLib instanceof Object)
    {
        console.log('client uses our lib, successfuly');//wouldn't be accessible if it contained errors
    }
    console.log(reslt.myLib);//shows full object, so you can verify it's the right one
```

*Note:*
This code is **un-tested**, I just wrote it off the top of my head. It may contain silly typo's. It's not a copy-pastable answer to all of your prayers.
I do believe the `page.evaluate` callback is able to return something, however: it's running in the context of the loaded page, and is sandboxed, so you may have to *force* an error:

```
page.evaluate(function()
{
    Array.forEach(document.querySelectorAll('script'), [function(elem)
    {
        if (/yourScript\.js/.test(elem.getAttribute('src')))
        {
            throw {message: 'Script found',
                   nodeSrc: elem.getAttribute('src'),
                   pageUrl: location.href,
                   myLib  : yourGlobalVar}//<-- cf remarks on jQ-like usage
        }
    }]);
});
```

By throwing this custom error, which isn't being caught, so it'll end up in the console, you force the `page.onConsoleMessage` handler to deal with this exception. That could be a way around the sandbox restrictions, in a way, if they're causing the infinite loop issue to occur.

Comment: should the /yourScriptName\ be replaced with: myjavascript or /myjavascript\ ?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen: it's a regex, so should be replaced with `/jquery\.min\.js/` if the script you're looking for is `jquery.min.js`. change it to `/jquery\.(min\.)?js/` to match both `jquery.js` and `jquery.min.js`...

Comment: Thats what i thought but when i run this on my own website (www.marcrasmussen.dk) i don't get any feed back (nothing is logged) it just keeps running forever!'

Comment: @MarcRasmussen: What exactly are you running on your website? It might be better to replace the `Array.forEach.apply`-bit with a simple loop, and just to log every iteration. I've just written this code off the top of my head, no tests at all, so there might be some errors in there...

Comment: on my website i have the following scripts:

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
<script charset="utf-8" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js">
<script src="Javascripts/kontakt.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="Javascripts/ommig.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="Javascripts/projekter.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="Javascripts/android.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js" type="text/javascript">

Comment: But shouldn't it stop even though it doesnt find my the correct script?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen: I've no idea what you're on about. Post the code you're using in your question, along with the version of phantomjs you're using, and what its output is...

Comment: @MarcRasmussen: Try wrapping the `var reslt = page.evaluate` bit in an `if (status == 'success'){/*all code here*/}` branch. I'm not psychic... also: try running the command from the command-line. It might be that the user running php doesn't have the rights to run phantomjs

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem by running it from the console i got the following error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Array.forEach.apply')

  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():4
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():12
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():12

Comment: @MarcRasmussen: Well then, replace the `Array.forEach` with a regular `for (var i=0;i<scripts.length;i++)`. That's standard JS debugging! Anyways, I've edited my code so the problem should be fixed now

Answer (score 1):

**Is it possible to check if a site has a certain JavaScript?**

You could do two things, where I think the one using JavaScript would be easier to implement.

*Using PHP:*

- fetch the content from the URLs in your database
- load it into a [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php) and search for a specific part of your code
- extract all external JavaScript files from that document

  - fetch them too and search for a specific code part within

*Using JavaScript*

- implement an AJAX request within a constructor or an initiate method
- send the current domain where the script is executed and compare it to the list in your database

*Self hosting*

- as discussed while writing this answer, this is another possibility, as your log can show all pages that this script accessed

**Is it possible to check if the javascript is running without errors?**

This one is a bit more complicated as you have check this during runtime. Imagine the user of your script extends or modifies your code or simply uses it in a wrong way or has something that conflicts with your code. Maybe this code is never reached, as it invokes some user interaction, that may or may not be triggered.

One possibility would be to send an AJAX request back to you, when an error occured. You can check out [`window.onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2Fwindow.onerror) for that purpose:

```
window.onerror = function(message, url, lineNumber) {}
```

This will give you some detailed information, that you can pass to your server using an AJAX request.

Comment: Using PHP won't validate any JS, and doesn't account for pages that use require.js or lazyload and the like...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I never said, that fetching the page using PHP will execute any JavaScript code. But you can search whether a part of the script occurs somewhere. And yes, it might fail when lazy loading is used. That's why I would recommend a JavaScript solution over a PHP solution. As the OP asked whether and how it is possible using PHP too, I simply answered that part as well.

Answer (score 0):

A roundabout or rather a naive way would be create a dummy object definition with a unique name say 'your_company_name_'+some_hash. like abc_45xcd.

```
//your custom js file

//BEWARE! this is global namespace. 

function abc_45xcd(){
      console.log('abc_45scd custom js is loaded');
}
```

When you click test button you can try creating a new object

```
   var x = new abc_45scd();
```

You can check the constructor and type for checking if its your 'own' custom dummy object.

**Note:** This is actually a naive solution, as some one might create an object of same name in their script. **Also, it pollutes global namespace for no reason.**