# Unable to execute javascript using PHPunit Selenium

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I am trying to execute a javascript code using PHPUnit Command. It executes the PHP code and sends email and other stuffs.

But there is some javascript code inside that php file that sends some data to third party url. That seems to be not working.

Any thoughts as how to execute the javascript code?

Comment: [Perhaps phantom.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329760/check-if-my-javascript-is-loaded-on-a-site/18330524#18330524) can help?

Comment: This should be covered by the support documents. Also your question does not have enough specifics for a concrete answer, voting to as unclear.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are using PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase and come hia from google.

@see https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/issues/160

It should be as:

```
$this->execute(array(
    'script' => $javaScriptCode,
    'args'   => array()
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [instaclick webdriver](https://github.com/instaclick/php-webdriver) you can execute javascript by using [execute](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/session/%3asessionId/execute)

for example:

```
$this->session->execute(array('script' => $script, 'args' => array())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming you mean the PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Command.

If you're getting 'waiting for evaluate.js load failed', it could be because your Firefox has upgraded to v23. If so you need to upgrade Selenium to 2.35 which has fixed this issue.
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6051#c9

You may also need to update PHPUnit Selenium due to a change in the server handshake fixed here https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/pull/266