# PHPUnit-Selenium - How to execute javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, phpunit

I was looking for answers and I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915571/unable-to-execute-javascript-using-phpunit-selenium). So I try to execute my script like this:

```
class viewerTest extends LoginLoader{    
public function testNewViewer(){
    $this->url('new-viewer.php');
    $this->byName('viewers_streetname')->value('street');    
    $script = file_get_contents("./viewerScript.js");
    $this->execute(array(
        'script' => $script,
        'args'   => array()
    ));
 }}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. It should check, if mandatory inputs are filled in and then write names of inputs, which hasn't been filled. But no name of input is listed.

Am I doing anything wrong?

PS: The function file_get_contents() is working.

Here is viewerScript.js :

```
function valid_viewer_submit(){

    var datastring = $("#edit-viewer").serialize();
    ...
    ...
    ...    
    error_div.innerHTML = error;
};
```

Comment: Okay, so what's the full code? If this is it, it won't run because it needs to be in some sort of class for `$this` to be meaningful.

Comment: Of course. The script is already added.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Already fixed.

I don't know why, but when I change the javascript like this...:

```
// function valid_viewer_submit(){

      var datastring = $("#edit-viewer").serialize();
      ...
      ...
      ...    
      error_div.innerHTML = error;
// };
```

...it works.

Answer (score 2):

The included javascript was defining a function, but not calling it...

You had to add another line with:

```
$this->execute(array(
    'script' => 'valid_viewer_submit();',
    'args'   => array()
));
```